# Remove first multiline comment from file

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I'm trying to remove all the initial multiline comments from a large directory of source files using unix tools.

For example, I have this file `testfile.c`

```
/* 
   testfile.c
   get rid of me
*/

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
/* 
   keep me
*/
    return 0;
}


/* 
   keep me
*/
```

I've tried using sed like this:

```
sed '/\/\*/,/\*\//d' testfile.c
```

but that strips all multiline comments resulting in:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to do this and only remove the multiline comment if it starts at the very first line of the file and to leave all other comments in tact?

Comment: Are you removing licenses?

Comment: yes, with a plan to put them back once I'm done

Comment: `^` is anchor tag for matching pattern occurring at very beginning. So use it like this `/^\/\*/,/\*\//d`

Comment: That's an anchor for the start of the line, not the start of the file. That doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Check my [regex](https://regex101.com/r/tE6fY1/2). It matches the first occurrence of the multi line comment. Use `g` for global search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assumes that there's nothing you want from your file before the first multiline comment. It just says to start printing after you see the `*/` that ends the first comment (and then never to stop again regardless of what's seen).

```
$ awk '!f&&/\*\//{f=1;next}f' testfile.c 

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
/*
   keep me
*/
    return 0;
}


/*
   keep me
*/
```

**Explanation:**

```
!f && /\*\// { f=1; next }
```

If the flag `f` is not set (that is, if `f` equals `0`, which it does when the program begins), and the current line contains the pattern `*/` (where both characters require escaping with `\`), then set the flag to `1` and go immediately to the next line (without printing).

```
f
```

Print the current line if the flag `f` is set to `1` (and recall that we only arrive here if the `next` statement was *not* executed, thereby avoiding to print the last line of the initial comment).

Comment: You're welcome; explanation added --- if anything still not clear let me know.

Comment: More concisely: `awk 'f; /*\//{f=1}' testfile.c`.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your part `/\/\*/,/\*\//d` with GNU sed in `1,/\*\//{ ... }`:

```
sed '1,/\*\//{ /\/\*/,/\*\//d }' file
```

Output:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
/* 
   keep me
*/
    return 0;
}


/* 
   keep me
*/
```

Comment: That works as well. Can you explain the `1,` part that you added?

Comment: `1,/\*\//{ ... }` limits sed's actions to the range from first line (`1`) to first line with `*/` (escaped: `\*\/`).

Answer (score 0):

if your comments all end the same way
try something like

```
awk 'BEGIN {while($1 != "*/") getline}{print}'
```

otherwise you will have to do something fancier looking at the last two chars of a line till you find the end of the first comment.

This has the feature of not testing any line after it has done its job.

Comment: This will spin off into an infinite loop if the `getline` fails, has other issues, and is a completely unnecessary use of `getline`. See http://awk.info/?tip/getline`

Answer (score -1):

```
sed '/\/\*/,/\*\// s/.*//g' filename | awk '!/^$/'
```

1. Matching by pattern ranges and replacing all by nothing.
2. Removing empty lines

Output:

> ```
>   int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
>         return 0;
>         }
> ```

Comment: this removes all comments which is not the OP wants.